# Slice notation in a tuple of lists (simple question)

Tags: python, tuples

Why this

```
print(tuplun[0:][1:])
tuplun = (["one", "two", "three"], ["hello", "scope"], ["pedro"])
```

results in this

```
(['hello', 'scope'], ['pedro'])
```

and not in this?

```
(["two", "three"], ["hello", "scope"], ["pedro"])
```

Is there a way to achieve the last one?

Comment: You take slice `[0:]` of your tuple (which is the whole tuple) and from that you take slice `[1:]`, which omits the first element. So you get the whole tuple except without the first element.

Comment: See [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/3890632)

Comment: `tuplun = tuplun[0][1:] + tuplin[1:]`

Comment: It seems that your requested result is inconsistent,  all but first for the first  sub-list, then all of the sub-list.

Comment: @timroberts Thanks for the answer! but I got this error: "can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list " with your method

Comment: @ChristianSama It would need to be `(tuplun[0],) + tuplun[1:]`, or `tuplun[:1] + tuplun[1:]`.  Both of those produce the original `tuplun`.

Comment: Sorry.  `tuplun = (tuplun[0][1:],) + tuplun[1:]`.  The first needs to be turned in to a one-tuple.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
tuple([item[-2:] for item in tuplun])
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, note, getting each slice only operates on the outer tuple and that the lists inside are not sliced at all.

The first part of the expression [0:] means everything after and including the first element which means everything. This, therefore, does nothing. The next section [1:] means everything after and including the second element which means everything except the first element so ["one", "two", "three"] is thrown away.

```
tuplun = (["one", "two", "three"], ["hello", "scope"], ["pedro"])
tuplun2 = (tuplun[0][1:],)+tuplun[1:] # The comma is there to declare it is a tuple
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, which asked how to do it.

Comment: @TimRoberts Sorry. Added Solution.